# select from a SCROLL DOWN MENU. write at least 1 character,wait to be visible and then press enter or click

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have to choose from a scroll down menu using java and selenium but first i have to write at least one letter or the whole word.

java
First i tried this but it's not a dropdown menu. From the id i get this info : (s2id_autogen3)

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathLoc.STATUS_SELECT.getLocator())));
        select.selectByVisibleText("OPEN");
```

But this doesn't work.

also i try other ways like webdriverwait
waituntilvisible,clicable etc but nothing happens

NOW I DO THIS:

```
 WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.id("s2id_autogen3"));
     input.sendKeys("OPEN"); // I SEND THE WORD I WANT, I TRIED click.();, i tried using keywords and enter but doesn't work.
```

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Enter first character
driver.findElement(By.xpath(“path”)).sendkeys(“first_latter”);

// Wait for the element to be visible if there is a loader visible after entering apply invisibility check for loader
WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(“element”));

// Click on the element
driver.findElement(By.xpath(“path”)).click();
```